# Python, parse html form

Tags: python, html, forms

how I can  get  input from html forms on other sites?
I want it to return a dictionary such as:

```
form = [('name' = 'somename', 'type' = 'text', 'value':''},{' name' = 'somename', 'type' = 'submit', 'value': ' submit ').
```

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a HTML file (possibly returned from `urllib.urlopen`-ing a url), or is this some Django based thing?

Comment: I try parse forms from other sites.

Answer (score 3):

you probably wont be able to retrieve form data from other users on other sites. If you wish to use a script to send data to a form, [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html) is one tool that makes this quite easy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but forms unfortunately not static and each time different, therefore is necessary the full analysis.
In mechanize it will be not absolutely convenient.

Comment: In that case, use lxml.html to parse the document, find form and input tags (possibly using xpath queries), and so on.

Comment: Derek, surely the forms are being generated using the `<form>` tag. This should be all that you need to get started. If the forms are  indeterministic, no script will be able to assist you. If you mean the forms are generated by client-side JavaScript, then browser automation may help.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah mechanize is sweet !

```
import mechanize

# Browser
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

# we inspect the all form element in the http://stackoverflow.com
br.open('http://stackoverflow.com')
for form in br.forms():
    print form
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at mechanize, lxml.html and BeatifulSoup.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is discontinued. Better not to mention.

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` is also much slower than `lxml.html`